# monaco-editor: how to subscribe / listen native commands / actions as 'actions.find'

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, monaco-editor

For a long time I've been trying to find a way, example or information about how I can subscribe or listen native commands/actions as `actions.find`.

My case is - to create some side-effect when user use *"Find Matches"* functionality in editor's workbench (called by keyboard shortcut or context-menu), at finally I want to get as argument 'searching 'substring' in my effect.

Hopefully the community can help me or place some similar case resolving sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After debugging and studying the source code of monaco-editor, I found, as it seems to me, the correct solution for using the API (IMHO) for my case.

We can use API of **FindController**, that is one of permanently contributions in each instance, we can use there public method **onFindReplaceStateChange**

```js
// to get relevant FindController from editor instance we can use
var findController = editor.getContribution('editor.contrib.findController')

// to get FindReplaceState from FindController
var findSearchState = editor.getContribution('editor.contrib.findController').getState();

// to subscribe to 'find matches' event bus
editor.getContribution('editor.contrib.findController')
   .getState().onFindReplaceStateChange(
       (...rest) => console.log('FindReplaceStateChange: ', ...rest)
   );

// to force & silent set current search substring
editor.getContribution('editor.contrib.findController').setSearchString('foo-bar');

// to programmatically call search with options, 
// not 'editor.getAction('actions.find').run()' (that not have arguments) 
editor.getContribution('editor.contrib.findController').start({
    forceRevealReplace: false,
    seedSearchStringFromSelection: false,
    seedSearchStringFromGlobalClipboard: false,
    shouldFocus: false,
    shouldAnimate: false,
    updateSearchScope: false
});
```

I have prepared an example with explanations for solving my case (synchronization of search between several editors) on a CodeSandbox -
[Monaco Editor [ Multiple Instances search sync case ]](https://codesandbox.io/s/monaco-editor-multiple-instances-search-sync-case-myegc?file=/src/index.js:3650-4193)

[screencast 'how it works' (GIF)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIWCe.gif)